# ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_client'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, rodeo

I am trying to install RODEO on my debian jessie box. I've successfully pip installed rodeo and the installation was completed without any issues. However, when I type `rodeo` on the command line I am greeted with the following error message:

```
xxxxxx@yyyyy:~$ rodeo 
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated. You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rodeo/kernel.py", line 3, in <module>
    from jupyter_client import BlockingKernelClient
ImportError: No module named 'jupyter_client'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rodeo", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('rodeo==0.4.4', 'console_scripts', 'rodeo')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 549, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2542, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2202, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2208, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rodeo/cli.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .rodeo import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rodeo/rodeo.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .kernel import Kernel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rodeo/kernel.py", line 5, in <module>
    from IPython.kernel import BlockingKernelClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ipykernel import comm, inprocess
ImportError: No module named 'ipykernel'
```

Could someone shed some light, as I have ipython installed. When searched for jupyter client in apt repos, I couldn't fine one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Jupyter is the new name of ipython, perhaps you have an old version. Try `pip install jupyter[notebook]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IPython 4.0 has [split](https://blog.jupyter.org/2015/08/12/first-release-of-jupyter/) into many packages, many of the notebook- and execution-related ones now being part of Jupyter.

If rodeo supports the 4.0 APIs, you can install these with:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

(*Almost* anything that worked with IPython 3 should work with IPython 4 and Jupyter, as long as the extra packages are installed. IPython includes shims for the imports that have moved.)

If that doesn't work, rodeo may require IPython 3.x for now. You can pin IPython to 3.x with:

```
pip install 'ipython[notebook]<4'
```